# Sort is not working with forEach instead it is working with map

Tags: javascript, sorting, filter, foreach

I have the below piece of code

```
Object.entries(obj)
            .map((arr) => {
                if (columnArray.indexOf(arr[0].toLowerCase()) > -1) {
                    return { value: arr[1], name: arr[0] };
                }
            })
            .sort(function(a, b) {
                return columnArray.indexOf(a.name.toLowerCase()) - columnArray.indexOf(b.name.toLowerCase());
            })
```

with map sort is working fine but when i have modified the code as below

```
Object.entries(obj).filter((arr)=>columnArray.indexOf(arr[0].toLowerCase()) > -1)
                .forEach((arr) => { 
                    console.log('array value-->',arr);      
                        return { value: arr[1], name: arr[0] };                 
                })
                .sort(function(a, b) {
                    return columnArray.indexOf(a.name.toLowerCase()) - columnArray.indexOf(b.name.toLowerCase());
                })
```

I got an error like 'sort is undefined',Could someone help me here.

Comment: `forEach()` does not *return*....

Comment: `.forEach` doesn't return anything. `.map` returns the new array. The two are not interchangeable.

Answer (score 0):

It is because "`forEach`" does not return anything and `map` does return new array that is why it working with `map` and not `forEach`. With "`forEach`" you can modify objects while looping like below

```
let newArr = []
Object.entries(obj).filter((arr)=>columnArray.indexOf(arr[0].toLowerCase()) > -1)
                .forEach((arr) => { 
                    console.log('array value-->',arr);      
                        newArr.push({ value: arr[1], name: arr[0] });                 
                })

newArr.sort(function(a, b) {
              return columnArray.indexOf(a.name.toLowerCase()) - columnArray.indexOf(b.name.toLowerCase());
           })
```

Answer (score 0):

`forEach()` executes the callback function once for each array element &  `returns` the value `undefined` and is not `chainable`.

In your case you are chaining `sort` with `forEach` which will not work.

Check more here [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)